# Fancybox messing up browser history with 'iframe' setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 1.3.4 with the iframe setting which loads in another page into an iframe.

```
$(".fancy").click(function(){
    return false;
});

$(".fancy").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    overlayOpacity: 0.8,
    overlayColor: '#222',
    showNavArrows: false
});
```

A link looks like this

`<a id="map_link" class="fancy" href="http://example.com/page">link</a>`

Problem is that whenever I click a link, it loads the iframe correctly but also forces the parent page to navigate to itself again. So this means if I open and close the fancybox 10 times, I now have 10 more items in my browser history of the parent page. Tested in all browsers and am having the problem across the board.

**EDIT**: [Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX9A/1/)
That pretty much mimics what I have on my site, fancybox-wise. Using jQuery 1.5, latest fancybox and testing in Chrome 11 and Firefox 3.6.14. When I click on the link 5 times, I get 5 instances of the parent frame site in my browsing history.

Comment: Better than `return false;` would be jQuery’s `event.preventDefault()`. ([link to API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/))

Comment: Can you add a working jsFiddle of the testcase?

Comment: @Exelian Added the test case, still have the problem in jsFiddle in the browsers I'm testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the [unpacked source code for FancyBox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1922282/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js), you will find

`content.find('iframe').attr('src', isIE6 && /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:void(false)' : 'about:blank');`

on line 946. If you comment that out it will fix the issue that you are having. As for what it does, it looks like it has to do with [an IE 'feature'](http://gemal.dk/blog/2005/01/27/iframe_without_src_attribute_on_https_in_internet_explorer/). However, I am not sure why it is necessary.

Comment: If that is confirmed the answer, then nice find!